# Inserting into column1 from column2 just the rows which do not exist already

Tags: psql

I have two columns in different tables. I frequently need to update a column based on the value of the second column. So how can I insert **only** the new values into my column?

Table A has col1 table B has col2:

A has values: 1 2 3

B has values: 1 2 3 4

I need to update A.col1 so that it has the value 4 in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will add only the row with value 4 in table A.col1

`INSERT INTO A(col1)
SELECT col2 FROM B 
WHERE col2 NOT IN 
(SELECT col1 FROM A);`

Thanks for your help anyways

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand the question.  I think you are asking how do you insert from A.col1 into B.col2 where there is no value yet for B.col2?  In that case:

```
update table B set B.col2 = A.col1 from A where B.someId = A.someId and B.col2 is null;
```